# disabling namespace attributes in serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

Am using following code to deserialize an object,

> ```
>         using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
>         {
>             try
>             {
>                 XmlWriterSettings writerSettings1 = new XmlWriterSettings();
>                 writerSettings1.CloseOutput = false;
>                 writerSettings1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
>                 writerSettings1.Indent = false;
>                 writerSettings1.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
> ```

```
                XmlWriter writer1 = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, writerSettings1);

                XmlSerializer xs1 = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType(), string.Empty);
                xs1.UnknownAttribute += new XmlAttributeEventHandler(xs1_UnknownAttribute);
                xs1.UnknownElement += new XmlElementEventHandler(xs1_UnknownElement);
                xs1.UnknownNode += new XmlNodeEventHandler(xs1_UnknownNode);
                xs1.UnreferencedObject += new UnreferencedObjectEventHandler(xs1_UnreferencedObject);
                xs1.Serialize(writer1, obj);
                writer1.Close();

            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                return null;
            }
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            serializeObjectDoc.Load(memoryStream);

            return serializeObjectDoc.DocumentElement;
```

After this when i check the returning node i get two extra attributes
{Attribute, Name="xmlns:xsi", Value="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"}    object {System.Xml.XmlAttribute}
{Attribute, Name="xmlns:xsd", Value="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"} object {System.Xml.XmlAttribute}

I want to know how to disable these two attributes

Comment: Why do you want to "disable" those attributes? They shouldn't harm anything.

Comment: They shouldn is a hypothetical statement.
I do not want extra attributes in my element,thats why.BCos i am using the same node in a xml which is read by different component.I want to make sure it gets exactly same inputs as it needs

Comment: Am rolling back the edited version.
Please put comments if u need any editing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XmlSerializerNamespaces` to the rescue; a simple (but complete) example:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System;
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    static void Main()
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, new Foo { Bar = "abc" }, ns);
    }
}
```